# Lorsque / au moment où / après que

Tags: vocabulaire

Bonjour,

> Lorsque Michel et moi reviendrons à la maison, il vous appellera et moi
> je partirai pour vous rendre visite.

Antidote définit *lorsque* comme *au moment où*, mais dans mon exemple *lorsque* signifie plutôt *après que*. Michel ne soulèvera pas le combiné dès qu'il franchira le seuil. Pourtant, je n'ai trouvé dans aucun dictionnaire que *lorsque* est synonyme de *après que*. Tous disent que *lorsque* = *au moment où*.

Pourriez-vous m'expliquer le rôle de *lorsque* dans ma phrase ?

Merci

Answer (score 2):

J'aurais écrit :

> Lorsque Michel et moi serons revenus à la maison, il vous appellera et moi je partirai pour vous rendre visite.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour votre réponse. Oui, votre proposition est meilleure et cela résout le problème.